# Get incoming links number for graph element in jointJS

Tags: jquery, graph, element, jointjs, rappid

In jointJS I want for every element to check the number of incoming connected links.So this is the code I made according to documentation but it doesn't work:

```
 _.each(this.graph.getElements(), function(element) {

    var inboundLinksCount = this.graph.getConnectedLinks(element, {inbound: true}).length;
    alert(inboundLinksCount); 
    }
```

This is the documentation of `getConnectedLinks` in jointJS:
http://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v1.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getConnectedLinks

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the below
instead of this.graph you could use your graph variable name at both places where 'this.graph' is. for debugging try console.log(graph.getElements) and graphe.getConnectedLinks(element)) if it writes any output on the console.

```
_.each(this.graph.getElements(), function(element) {

    var inboundLinksCount = this.graph.getConnectedLinks(element, {inbound: true});
    alert(inboundLinksCount); 
    }
```